# vim shortcut to move right one position without leaving insertion mode

Tags: vim, editor

I really like the idea of not need to leave the typing position and accomplish everything using vim. However I find myself kinda have to use the right arrow at certain points.

```
if (boolean)
```

I often find my self doing this, after finishing the expression within the parenthesis, I have to do `<Esc>la` to move to the end of the line or `<right arrow>` or `<shift><4>a`

Is there any tricks to do the same thing as right arrow in insertion mode without having to move that far?

I am thinking of mapping that combination to capslock. But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: What's wrong with `<Right>` and `<End>`?

Comment: @romainl Well people using vim generally discourage using those arrow keys.

Comment: `<Esc>la` and `<Esc>$a` can be simplified a bit to `<Esc>A`.  Moving in insert mode is pretty frowned upon, and your best bet is to use arrow keys unless you want your own mappings.

Comment: Well *I* don't discourage using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this in my vimrc:

```
inoremap <c-l> <esc>%%a
```

It brings you to the right side of current bracket pairs, and keeps the insert mode.

```
foo(bar(bla(whateverI)))  "I is cursor, type Ctrl-l
foo(bar(bla(whatever)I))
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in insert mode to run any normal mode command and then you will be back again to insert mode.

---

For up and down arrow keys they have already default shortcuts during insert mode:

<kbd>Up</kbd>    :  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>Down</kbd> :  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: I mean I still ends up pressing 3 or more keys right?

Comment: Then train your fingers to use arrow keys otherwise add some mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Most bracketing plugins provide a way(/s) to move past end the next closing bracket character(s). Here, usually, hitting `)` would have been enough. Some old plugins used to use `CTRL+J` independently of the bracket pairs.

If you use a bracketing plugin, just read the documentation. If you use a snippet plugin that fills your control statements, it should also provide a way to jump directly to the next placeholder (here, the action associated to the `if`), if the snippet is correctly defined. Most plugins use `tab`, mines use the `<c-j>` or `<M_del>` by default.

If you have abbreviations that inserts your control-statements, well, you are missing stuff that we have defined in more evolved plugins more than a decade ago. Balancing brackets automatically is nice to avoid stupid errors, but without a way to go after the closing brackets, it's really a counterproductive PITA to use.

PS: BTW, sometimes efficiency with our keyboard requires us to use it to its full capability, i.e. we have arrow keys waiting to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I use [auto-pairs plugin](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs).

Beside all the pair goodies, hitting the closing pair will move the cursor after it:

```
input : if (boolean|) (press ) at |)
output: if (boolean)|

input : function({ foo: 'bar'| }) (press } at |)
output: function({ foo: 'bar' }|) (press ) at |)
final : function({ foo: 'bar' })|
```